# How do I get a pretty visual diff for svn?

Tags: svn, diff

I want tkdiff (or something like it) to display my 'svn diff' so that I can switch files in the tkdiff interface itself.

(I'm using a mac.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an SVN client. It will enable additional functionality not available with command line SVN.

On Windows, I recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/). It allows integration with third party diff tools such as [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/?gclid=CKG7no3Im6QCFQsCbAod9lpyFQ).

[Similar tools](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/58) exist on other operating systems which allow you to do the same.

Comment: Yep, TortoiseSVN for windows. And for linux you have Kompare and KDiff3.

Comment: A list just for OS X: http://theappleblog.com/2009/02/23/12-subversion-apps-for-os-x/

Answer (score 38):

One windows I use TortoiseSVN, best SCM client on the planet.

On Linux the closest I can get is installing meld and running the following subversion command:

```
svn diff MyFile.txt --diff-cmd meld
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me? (and I have meld installed).

Comment: You can make the '--diff-cmd' option permanent by adding the line: "diff-cmd = meld" to the file: ~/.subversion/config.

Comment: Also, another nice graphical diff tool is 'tkdiff', but I imagine it all comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @Avian00 I've since moved on to git :-)

Comment: @DavidDoria meld doesn't understand the parameters svn passes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7418087/420867) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20355357/420867) answer for more info.

Answer (score 9):

I am using Mac OS but same thing works for other Unix System(may be meld needed for them )

But in Mac,
Just install tkdiff using macport or brew 
Like
brew install tkdiff
or 
sudo port install tkdiff

Then Simple type the following command in you SVN project folder.

```
svn diff --diff-cmd tkdiff
```

Comment: I get an error: `exec of 'tkdiff' failed: No such file or directorysvn: E200012: 'tkdiff' returned 255`

Answer (score 6):

Install [ColorDiff](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/)

```
$ sudo apt-get install colordiff
```

Configure Subversion Client

Open up `~/.subversion/config` in your favorite text editor, and search for this line:

```
# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
```

Add this line right below it (I like keeping the default examples intact):

```
diff-cmd = colordiff
```

restart terminal and now you can see colorful `svn diff`

Answer (score 3):

If confined to a Linux console I find it very helpful to put the following function in my .bashrc

```
svndiff() { vimdiff <(svn cat "$1") "$1";  }
```

The command

```
svndiff MyFile.txt
```

will then open vimdiff and show you the differences side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks,  since 2010, I did start using vimdiff, and I've upgraded to mercurial.

Comment: Didn't know about svn cat, that's pretty cool.  Clever script.

Answer (score 2):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) as many already have mentioned.  It has a built in text file comparison app callled TortoiseMerge.  But a more pretty text file compare tool is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), which if you install can integrate with TortoiseSVN.  It's great even for non-SVN related file comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/idiff is just avesome filter:

```
svn diff | idiff
```

Comment: This is nice, kind of like default git.  Thanks.

Comment: How to use on a Mac?

Comment: Mac should run it without problem

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat convoluted and involves writing a wrapper script to emulate the diff and diff3 tools

[Here is more info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) about it.

Answer (score 1):

When you type "svn help diff", you will get an option called "--diff-cmd ARG". Here is a simple example to use tkdiff to see the changes from the earlier version.

```
svn diff --diff-cmd tkdiff adc_ctrl.sv -r 768
```

Here, 768 is the svn revision number.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this question is a decade old. SVN is basically dead.