# How to set up svn conflict resolution with meld?

Tags: svn, meld

I've specified `merge-tool-cmd = meld` in my Subversion config. When I go to resolve a merge conflict using option l from the presented conflict resolution options, I receive the message:

```
meld: error: too many arguments (wanted 0-4, got 5)
The external merge tool exited with exit code 2
```

Can anyone diagnose the problem/provide a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First a warning! It is very easy to end up losing your local edits if you get this wrong! Test test test!

I'm afraid the script from pmod's link does not work with svn 1.6 (current in Ubuntu 11.04). Putting together code from [pmod's link](http://codingundertheinfluence.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-meld-as-your-external-diff3.html) and [here](http://berikontech.blogspot.com/2010/11/merging-svn-using-meld.html) and advice [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools), I made this script that seems to work ok:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# svn merge-tool python wrapper for meld
import sys
import subprocess

try:
   # path to meld
   meld = "/usr/bin/meld"

   # file paths
   base   = sys.argv[1]
   theirs = sys.argv[2]
   mine   = sys.argv[3]
   merged = sys.argv[4]

   # the call to meld
   # For older meld versions:
   # cmd = [meld, mine, base, theirs, merged]
   # New meld versions: >= 1.8.4
   cmd = [meld, mine, base, theirs, '-o', merged]

   # Call meld, making sure it exits correctly
   subprocess.check_call(cmd)
except:
   print "Oh noes, an error!"
   sys.exit(-1)
```

Save this somewhere sensible (eg `/usr/local/bin/svn-merge-meld.py`) and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/svn-merge-meld.py
```

Then edit `~/.subversion/config` and uncomment the line `merge-tool-cmd =`, and set the path to your command.

Note that when a conflict occurs, you will be prompted what to do with it. You need to type a single `l` and  for svn to run this script. When you've finished your merge, you need to type an `r` to resolve the conflict and copy the merged version to the working copy.

Comment: Remove os and shutil imports -- they are not used anymore.

Comment: Seems that the call cmd for meld has changed -- i use `cmd = [meld, mine, base, theirs, '-o', merged]`  (meld 1.8.4).
`

Comment: Throwing away the error information with that catch isn't very useful.

Comment: Great answer. I voted before, then now having been back 2nd time (the need to resolve svn conflict shows up again..) and wanted to vote again :)

Answer (score 11):

The [drevicko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418087/938111) is correct but requires Python. This answer is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

base=${1?1st arg is the 'base' file}
theirs=${2?2nd arg is 'theirs' file}
mine=${3?3rd arg is 'mine' file}
merged=${4?4th arg is the 'merged' file}

cat "$mine" > "$merged"

meld -L "Base=${base##*/}"           "$base"   \
     -L "Mine->Merged=${merged##*/}" "$merged" \
     -L "Theirs=${theirs##*/}"       "$theirs" \
     -o "$merged"
```

Copy the above script in file `svn-merge-meld.sh` and provide execution permission with:

```
chmod +x svn-merge-meld.sh
```

Finally edit your [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) configuration:

```
vi ~/.subversion/config
```

and enable `merge-tool-cmd`:

```
[helpers]
merge-tool-cmd = /path/to/svn-merge-meld.sh
```

Comment: meld 3.18.0 only takes 3 arguments again. How to support that?

Comment: Thank you @JohnyTex for your bug report ;) Ten years ago, Meld accepted up to 4 input files for a four-way merge. But this is not possible any more (since v1.8.4 apparently).  :'( I have fixed my answer. (I do not use SVN since many years)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use wrapper script to grab and put things subversion is out to the order needed for your diff tool (check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html)):

> The key to using external two- and three-way differencing tools (other
> than GNU diff and diff3, of course) with Subversion is to use wrapper scripts, which
> convert the input from Subversion into something that your
> differencing tool can understand, and then to convert the output of
> your tool back into a format that Subversion expects—the format that
> the GNU tools would have used.
> ...
>
> Subversion calls external diff programs with parameters suitable for
> the GNU diff utility, and expects only that the external program will
> return with a successful error code. For most alternative diff
> programs, only the sixth and seventh arguments—the paths of the files
> that represent the left and right sides of the diff, respectively—are
> of interest.

This is very well described [here](http://codingundertheinfluence.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-meld-as-your-external-diff3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I updated @drevicko answer to work with subversion>=1.14, meld>=3.20 and Python 3:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

# svn merge-tool python wrapper for meld
import sys
import subprocess

try:
   # path to meld
   meld = "/usr/bin/meld"

   # file paths
   base    = sys.argv[1]
   theirs  = sys.argv[2]
   mine    = sys.argv[3]
   merged1 = sys.argv[4]
   merged2 = sys.argv[5]

   print(14*"*" + " MELD was called with " + 14*"*")
   print(f"base    = {base}")
   print(f"theirs  = {theirs}")
   print(f"mine    = {mine}")
   print(f"merged1 = {merged1}")
   print(f"merged2 = {merged2}")

   # the call to meld
   cmd = [meld, mine, base, theirs, '-o', merged1, '--auto-merge', '-L', 'mine -> base(merged) <-theirs']

   # Call meld, making sure it exits correctly
   subprocess.check_call(cmd)
except Exception:
   print("There was an error calling meld!")
   sys.exit(-1)

print(50*"*")
```